# Как узнать список всех определённых макросов?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Как выяснить, какие макросы определяются в одной конкретной единице трансляции? Есть способ напечатать такой список из имён?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2224334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого использутеся параметры `-dM -E` компилятора GCC.

```
gcc -dM -E prog.c
```

Директивы, объявляющие макросы, будут выведены в стандартный поток, на терминал. Список включает в себя не только те имена, что были объявлены явно в исходном коде, но и внутренние макросы, предопределённые и заданные в командной строке — аргументы `-D`.

Comment: Для C++: `g++ -dM -E -x c++ - < /dev/null`